# Whats the relation between sectors and 2t2r?

Tags: telecommunication

I am quite new in telecommunication domain. I want to know what is the relation between sectors and 2T2R?
I know that 2T2R stands for 2 Transmitter, 2 receivers, but what is the connection with the sectors?

Comment: technical electrical questions are much better asked on the EE SE